# How to grab the left-most viewable page index from a multi-page android view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toggle, android-custom-view

Currently building a custom Toggle widget (aka Segmented control aka tab layout those type of things), by layering a viewpager with x visible pages on top of a linear layout.

Like this 
`........|......android screen...|`
`|..not..|visible|visible|visible|..not..|`

The issue is that pager.getCurrentItem() doesn't consistently return the left-most visible item, it returns the most recently dragged page.

If there is any easy solution to this, I'd love to hear it before I go trying to make a whole system for keeping track.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the use-case is and whether something like [this library](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager) helps.

If you're willing to manage your own paging, you could use `RecyclerView` instead of ViewPager, since setting a new `LinearLayoutManager` on that would allow you to `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition`, as described [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())

The way this could work is that you first set a horizontal layout manager:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Then you can use `layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` in your handling code. Check out the other methods available too - they are handy in getting the first/last, fully/partly visible item.

This approach is flexible, assumes the recyclerview's adapter count is the same as the number of segments you have, but you must manage scrolling to simulate paging as needed.